# Node.js and Express - How to get location of browser

Tags: node.js, geolocation, express

After researching for a while I couldn't find out how to get the location of the browser (By IP). I am also fairly new to Node.js and Express. Is there a module or some code to help you get the location of the browser viewing the node.js app? I need the longitude and latitude or at least the zip code.

Thanks

Comment: There is a great [peepcode screencast](http://peepcode.com/products/nodejs-i) that basically walks you through an example of doing exactly this and it was recently updated on 10 Feb 2012

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt that there is only one module. Have a look at https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules for common modules and you might try searching for `geo` at http://search.npmjs.org/ - and there's also [Nipster](http://eirikb.github.com/nipster/) and [Toolbox](http://toolbox.no.de/) for searching for modules.

TL;DR: [node-geoip](https://github.com/bluesmoon/node-geoip) seems to be what you are looking for.